# Adding class to all elements using :eq

Tags: jquery, sequence

I want to add the class 'second-col' to all second TD's in each row, but this isn't working:

```
$('table.tst3 tbody td:eq(1)').addClass('second-col');
```

Comment: What does the markup look like?  There is nothing wrong with this jQuery code as far as I can see.

Comment: Second that. The jQuery code looks fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [`nth-child`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/nthChild) instead, '`eq`' will [Reduce the set of matched elements to a single element](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/eq)

```
$('table.tst3 tbody td:nth-child(2)').addClass('second-col');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
$('table.tst3 tbody td:odd').addClass('second-col');
```

or

```
$('table.tst3 tbody td:even').addClass('second-col');
```

depending on what you want to select.

documentation:

[even](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/even)

[Odd](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/odd)

Answer (score 0):

using plain css selection:

```
    $('table.tst3 tbody td + td').addClass('second-col');
```

Note that if you have more than 2 columns, the ones after the second column will also be selected. So, depending on your markup this may - or may not be relevant: you would need to overwrite these additional columns with another jquery action (using td + td + td). But i thought i'd point to that possibility.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
$('table.tst3 tbody tr td:nth-child(2)').addClass('second-col');
```

Comment: This won't work as :eq(1) will reduce the set to only one element. So this code will affect only first row.